# What is the purpose of a bare package declaration, and what does it do?

Tags: haxe

What is the purpose of a bare package declaration, and what does it do? As in:

```
package;

class Main {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`package;` communicates that you are so-called "top-level", that means, you are not actually in a package.

You can leave it out, so this will work too:

```
class Main {
    //...
}
```

If you are in a package, it is required to define the type path at the top of the file, eg. `package foo.bar;` (where `foo.bar` is a folder `foo/bar` in a source path, defined by `-src` )

> More info https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-modules-and-paths.html